# I am a beginner in C# and need help creating a proper method

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, class, methods

Ok, here is my assignment at school.

1. Create a console application named CreateVehicle.
2. Develop a Vehicle class that captures the following information:

   a. Company

   b. Model

   c. MRSP

   d. Number of vehicles created.
3. Your class should have a null constructor and at least one additional constructor to collect the full information on creation.
4. Have a method to buy the vehicle.
5. Create an efficient way to print out all of the information collected on a vehicle.
6. Develop a class to test your Vehicle class. In this class do the following:

   a. Create the following vehicles from the information below:

   ```
   Car:          Model:    MSRP:
   Aston Martin  Vantage   $129,000
   Ford          Fusion    $ 28,678.99
   Honda         Civic EX  $ 18,713.27
   ```

   b. Exercise your Buy method by buying the Honda Civic.

   c. Use your print method to print out all relevant information on the vehicles above.

   d. When you buy your Honda print out the fact that you bought the Honda.
7. Bonus points (10). Include a flag item in your class that tells the status of whether the created vehicle was bought or not and have that status print out in your overall Vehicle class print method.

Here is the code I've come up with so far, but I'm not sure where to go from here or how to fix the parts with syntax problems. I'm definitely not sure how my BuyVehicle method is supposed to work:

Program.cs

```
using System;

namespace CreateVehicle
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Vehicle firstVehicle = new Vehicle("Aston Martin", "Vantage", 129000);
            Console.WriteLine(firstVehicle.ToString());

            firstVehicle.BuyVehicle(true);
            Console.WriteLine("You bought a {0}", firstVehicle.Model);

            Vehicle secondVehicle = new Vehicle("Ford", "Fusion", 28678.99);
            Console.WriteLine(secondVehicle.ToString());

            Vehicle thirdVehicle = new Vehicle("Honda", "Civic EX", 18713.27);
            Console.WriteLine(thirdVehicle.ToString());

        }
    }
}
```

Vehicle.cs

```
using System;

namespace CreateVehicle
{
    class Vehicle
    {
        public string companyName;
        private static int totalVehicles = 0;
        private string mModel;
        private string mMSRP;

        public Vehicle()
        {
            companyName = "Not assigned";
            mModel = "Not assigned";
            mMSRP = 0;

            totalVehicles++;
        }

        public Vehicle(string companyName, string model, double price)
        {
            this.companyName = companyName;
            mModel = model;
            mMSRP = price;

            totalVehicles++;
        } 

        public string Model
        {
            get
            {
                return mModel;
            }
        }

        public decimal MSRP
        {
            get
            {
                return mMSRP;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value >= 0)
                {
                    mMSRP = value;
                }
                else
                {
                    mMSRP = 0;
                }
            }
        }

       public string BuyVehicle(Boolean buy)
        {
            if (buy == true)
            {
                return mModel;
            }
            else
            {
                return "";
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "Vehicle Data:  \n\t" +
                   "Company Name:   " + companyName + "\n\t" +
                   "Model:          " + mModel + "\n\t" +
                   "MSRP:           " + mMSRP.ToString("C") + "\n\t" +
                   "Total vehicles: " + totalVehicles + "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you should put this code on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question is to broad - we won't do the work for you. To get better responses, edit the question and point out exactly what compiler errors/warnings you have issues with, or on what step you are stuck. Each problem should go into an own question.

Comment: Some things are underlined in red in the BuyVehicle method. I didn't think it was too broad since I wrote 99% of the code, and don't understand how my method is supposed to work. I don't know what to return on that method on the else statement.

Comment: It looks like most of your errors are because you are trying to do implicit casting from String to Double instead of expliciting casting them.

Comment: if (buy == true)
            {
                return mModel;
            }
            else
            {
                return ""; you are missing a closing } in your buyvehicle method..

Comment: thank you very much Jane Doe. Hopefully there isn't anything else wrong with the method.

Comment: anyone know what my invalid arguments are in the mMsrp.Tostring?

Comment: what's the problem you're facing now then? the code you've provided seems ok.. ?

Comment: I don't really understand why it want's to convert it to a string, since it should just be a number there.

Comment: when I try to run it I get "Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string'" etc

Comment: I have to agree with Anders Abel, no one will do the work for you.  If they do then you really will never learn and the best way learn is by doing it yourself and only being provided guidance on where to look for the answer.

Comment: What work? The code is written to what I know how to do! I bet there's 1 or 2 things I'm doing wrong...

Comment: @IQtheMC - You can ask about those specific problems, after looking for similar posts.

Comment: try removing the mMsrp.toString();. just make it + mMsrp +

Comment: Stick a break point on "Vehicle firstVehicle = new Vehicle("Aston Martin", "Vantage", 129000); " and step through it.  Then you will be able to find what line of code is causing the problem.

Comment: I've looked at similar posts. I guess I just need to turn it in and have my teacher tell me what I was hoping you guys would. I'm sure it will take him 5 seconds to figure out what I'm doing wrong and point out what I could change.

Comment: or maybe Jane will save me. Thanks again.

Comment: What the guys are trying to get across is you is that they are happy to point you in the correct direction but won't give you the answers.  You say that when you run it your getting this error.  Well the first thing to do is to track down the line of code that is causing the problem and then try and fix it. You fix it by googling and looking up the MSDN lib.  You never learn if people just give you the answer.

Comment: I've spotted your problem.  Have a look at your global variable declarations and then what values your assigning to them.  One of the variables you've mixed up the type in it's accessor and the value your passing into your vehicle constructor.

Comment: I've spent the last 4 hours or so trying to figure this one out. I've looked up everything. If I can't get an answer then I don't even see the point of the site. When I step into what you said to step into, I get 'cannot convert type int to string'. Makes no sense to me. The only int declared is totalVehicles and I don't want to convert it to a string.

Comment: actually, I may finally see thanks to you.

Comment: just got rid of 4 errors. 2 left. Thank you thank you thank you.

Comment: Have a look at variable declaration for mMSRP?  You've declared it as a string but then your assigning it to a 0.  Then your constructor is expecting a double and then in your accessor your expecting to return a decimal.  This is why I was telling you to step through your code.  Not only with vs but with your eyes following its path where its declared.  If your still having errors let me know what the errors are.  The purpose of this site is to help point you in the direction not give you the answer.  You will learn so much more figuring it out yourself and the satifaction.

Comment: Got it done. Thanks again to helpful computer programming geniouses like zeencat and Jane. Without you I would not be getting an A on this assignment and thanks to you I have learned a lot and will be better on the next assignment.

Comment: Great but as the guys said, always better to learn for yourself and ask for guidance not answers.

Comment: I will keep that in mind. Although you didn't exactly do this code for me. You gave me guidance, which is all I wanted, and I found what was wrong after that. I didn't even see your last comment until I fixed it. I'm pretty new and never stepped through a program before. Next time I'll try to be more specific in my question, but I  thought I had variables declared properly and was getting the error because of something else. Too new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at variable declaration for mMSRP? You've declared it as a string but then your assigning it to a 0. Then your constructor is expecting a double and then in your accessor your expecting to return a decimal. This is why I was telling you to step through your code. Not only with vs but with your eyes following its path where its declared. If your still having errors let me know what the errors are. The purpose of this site is to help point you in the direction not give you the answer. You will learn so much more figuring it out yourself and the satifaction

Answer (score 1):

I agree with zeencat 100%. The only way to trully learn something is by self discovery. Doing this will allow you too pick up many additional unknown pieces and best practices along the way. Your code does not look 'that bad' given that you mentioned you're a beginner, however I do notice a few things you should take notice of in your class:

To name one example: your class attributes (public string companyName;) should never be public, as this allows the end user to purposely or unintentionally break the code. These fields should always be private. Additionally, it's usually good practice to use Hungarian Notation when creating class attributes and including an underscore to denote the fields accessor status (public, private, etc.)

eg. _strCompanyName; or _strMSRP;

Doing it this way lets you know that this is a private string variable. When you look over your code to debug it later (as zeencat pointed out) it would have been much easier to spot the 'type mismatch' with _strmMsrp;

Lastly, it is always good to initialize your variables once you've declared them:

eg. string myString = ""; or double myNumber = 0.0; or  bool isTrue = true; etc.

Here is a link to tutorial series for C# fundamentals which I used to get started. After 3 years they are still the best I've seen. Every lesson taught, and every example given, are industry best practices.

[c# tutorial for beginners](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXmVym6L8dw&list=PLAC325451207E3105)

Best of luck to you.

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you. I'll make sure to all of that(except the notation for now. I'm just doing it the way they are teaching me.) Good to know the other way though since I'll probably need to do that soon. Thanks for the link too. Got it saved.